# Apache configuration file name without domain name

Tags: laravel-5, deployment, ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4

I have my Laravel project on an ubuntu 16.04 server and don't have a domain name. Now I should create the configuration file for my site to work with:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysitename.com.conf
```

**what should the file name be instead of mysitename.com.conf as I don't have a domain name ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename here is meaningless aside from the order in which they are processed. The server only cares about the configuration directives inside.  Just name it after your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have a domain name, you are not an a network. So use localhost.

Comment: What do you mean with " you are not on a network" ??

Comment: In other words: if you don‘t have a Domainname you could always use localhost or the IP of the server. The filename isnt really important. Important is what is in the file.